# Law of total expectation derivation

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

In the proof of the Law of Total Expectation, the following identity confuses me

$$P(X=x|Y)P(Y=y)=P(X=x,Y=y)$$

I this the conditional probability formula? Is $P(X=x,Y=y)=P(X=x \cap Y=y)$?

Comment: Yes, the comma is another way of denoting "and" or "$\cap$". By the way, in the first line you should have $P(X = x \mid Y = y)$ rather than $P(X = x \mid Y)$.

Comment: @angryavian: Thank you for the $P(X=x|Y=y)$ hint!

Answer (score 1):

Yes and yes, although for clarity $|Y$ should read $|Y=y$.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I will accept it tomorrow ... I have to sleep right now.